# Asyncio aiohttp populate list of HTML from list of URL

Tags: python, asynchronous, web-crawler, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to get a `list` of HTML source code from a `list` of URLs asynchronously with `asyncio` and `aiohttp` but I get 2 Exceptions:

1. `TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is ' TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001C92141F310>`
2. `raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed') RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`

This is my code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttpasync 

def main():
    tasks = []
    html_list = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in ['http://www.apple.com', 'http://www.google.cl']:
            async with session.get(url) as resp:
                tasks.append(html_list.append(await resp.read()))
        print(html_list[0])
        print(html_list[1])
        await(asyncio.wait(tasks))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This code **gets to print the html codes** of `['http://www.apple.com', 'http://www.google.cl']` but immediatly after I get the aforementioned Exceptions.

Comment: `html_list.append` returns `None`. When you try to await `tasks`, it contains nothing but a list of `None`s. At that point you've already awaited all of the requests so you don't even need `tasks`.

Comment: @dirn I removed the `tasks` `list`, replaced `tasks.append(html_list.append(await resp.read()))` with just `html_list.append(await resp.read())` and removed the `await(asyncio.wait(tasks))` line. HTML fetched codes are printed and I don't get the first error, but I still get the `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed` error.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that aren't quite right with your example:

1. You're not running anything concurrently. When you `await resp.read()` in your for loop, this blocks `main` until the result comes back. Perhaps this is what you want, but you need to use `asyncio.create_task` to run your requests concurrently.
2. As pointed out, you don't need the `task` array at all because of point number one. You can just append to `html_list`.
3. You don't need to call `asynio.wait` because you're not awaiting any tasks or coroutines at this point.

You can resolve your direct issues by what you have done in the comments, but a version that runs concurrently looks like this:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def read_url(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        return await resp.read()


async def main():
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in ['http://www.apple.com', 'http://www.google.cl']:
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(read_url(session, url)))
        html_list = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print(html_list[0])
        print(html_list[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Here we define a coroutine `read_url` which gets the contents of a single url. Then in the loop, you create a task for reading the url and append it to the `tasks` list. Then you use `asyncio.gather` - this will wait for all tasks to finish concurrently.

As written, I'm unable to reproduce your `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed` error.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I still get the error: `Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000022138327310>` `...(asyncio Traceback error details...)...` `raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`

Comment: @OliverMohrBonometti interesting that I'm not seeing this - how are you running your script and which versions of Python and aiohttp are you using? I'm using Python 3.7.8 and aiohttp 3.6.2

Comment: it is `Python 3.8` and `aiohttp 3.6.2`